# Install app button is not working

Tags: android

I have build my first calculator android app...
min sdk : 16  max : 25
It is working perfectly fine in many apps but some devices including my extra phone opens up the app but the install button is not wokring.. (I mean when I click on install nothing happens. However, when I click cancel it cancels the installation process)
I have tried allowing installation from unknown sources to opening developer mode. This has happened with several other devices surprisingly all were running android 6.0.

Comment: try restart your device

Comment: Thank you so much. it worked but could you please tell me what was the reason?